# JQuery getJSON For loop nested promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, async-await

I'm trying to resolve promises from a nested for loop:

```js
let fillInTable = () => {
    let result = []
    $.getJSON(`https://kvdb.io/${bucket}/?format=json`).then((data) => {
       data.map(each => $.getJSON(`https://kvdb.io/${bucket}/${each}`).then(o => {
          result.push(o)
       }));
    });
    return result
}

let random = fillInTable(); // appears to be []

// TODO: Wait for random to receive all the information from fillInTable() before executing anything else
```

The `random` is always empty, which I guess by default `getJSON` is async. I'm trying to use `await` but it doesn't work since it's not in an async function.

I tried to push all promises in an array and then use `Promise.all([...])` but doesn't work either.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: just `return $.getJSON(...)`.. within that you can use `return Promise.all(...)` then use `fillInTable().then(result => ...)` to handle the final result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've replaced the two URLs with some dummy JSON endpoints, in order to make this work. It should be working with your own endpoints also.

```js
let fillInTable = async () => {
    const data = await $.getJSON(`https://api.myjson.com/bins/awyt4`);
    const result = await Promise.all(
        data.map( each => $.getJSON(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?id=${each}`) )
    );
    return result
}


fillInTable()
.then( random => console.log( random ))
.catch( error => console.error( error )); // Always handle rejections in Promises ;)
```

Comment: thank you, this was what I didn't think of :).